# How to send two Recurring Cloud Message every week one after another and repeat again from Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send two messages every week one after another and repeat the process again to our app from Firebase Dashboard. I see there is a scheduling system for sending the message, but I am new in Firebase. I can't achieve this. Please help me.

My first message is "Need any help. Please contact support.", which I want to send Monday and another message is "Please give feedback here", which I want to send Tuesday in the same Week. In
Next week, repeat the same from the first message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

In the firebase dashboard, you can schedule the messages. Follow the steps in the dashboard and then click on **Scheduling** and click on **Custom** to be able to send a message one Monday and Tuesday.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad for the easy description. But i have one more question. If i have 10 messages and want to send one after another for 10 days. After 10 days it will begin sending from the first message.  Then what will be the process?

Comment: you can just delete the messages, if you dont want to send anymore

Comment: But i want to send every message after 10 days from it's first occurrence.

Comment: I mean if you dont want to send messages after 10 days you can just delete the message.

Comment: if you want to send every 10 days then click on **Scheduling** -> **Custom** -> **days**

Comment: Ok that's cool. One more thing. In the 'Subject to frequency limit', **"Once per user for this message"** does it mean, I can't send the same message again after 10 day's?

Comment: it means it is sent once and not more than that. So on day 1 it will be sent once then on day 10 it will be sent once